# Why is the Riemann sum less than the value of the integral?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

Why is $ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}\leq\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x}=\log 2 $?

Because I think: $$\int _0^1\frac{dx}{1+x}=\frac{1}{n}\sum _{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}$$

Why is the Riemann sum less than the value of the integral?

Comment: Choose any (finite) value of $n$ and draw a diagram of the integral with the Riemann sum indicated. You'll see immediately that they are not equal.

Comment: See below for more

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Expanding on comments above to give an intuitive idea of this result: write $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x}$ and set $n = 4$. A rough diagram:

[image]

Then, for example, the area of the first (left most) rectangle is

$$f(1+1/4) \cdot \Delta x = \frac{1}{1+1/4} \cdot \frac{1}{4}$$

The area of all four rectangles is

$$\sum_{k=1}^4 f(1 + k/4) \Delta x = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1 + k/n}$$

That area is strictly less than $\displaystyle \ \int_0^1 f(x) \ dx$; there is positive area in those 'white gaps' in between the top of the rectangles and the graph of $f$.

---

It shouldn't be hard to convince yourself intuitively that for *all* $n$,

$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1 + k/n} < \int_0^1 f(x) \ dx$$

Here's how I would prove it:

$f$ is strictly decreasing on $[0,1]$ as $f'(x) = -1/(1+x)^2 < 0$.

Thus on any interval $[(k-1)/n,k/n]$ for $k =1, 2, \cdots, n$, the minimum value of $f$ on that interval is $f(k/n)$. Hence

$$\int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n} f(x) \ dx > \int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n} f(k/n) \ dx = \int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n} \frac{1}{1+k/n} \ dx = \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + k/n}$$

Therefore

$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1 + k/n} < \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n} f(x) \ dx = \int_0^1 f(x) \ dx$$

Comment: I've edited my post to add a proof.

Comment: I could use a beer as well! Seriously though, I hope my post exemplifies an an important idea: nearly always in mathematics, we first develop a rough, intuitive understanding of the problem before we find the careful proof. We don't emphasize that enough on this site, imo.

Answer (score 2):

Because when $f$ is decreasing, then
$$
\frac 1n f\left(\frac kn\right)\le \int_{\frac{k-1}n}^{\frac kn} f(t)dt
$$

Comment: and when is increasing, the sign will be change?

Comment: of course. this is the integration of the inequality $t < \frac kn \implies f(t) \ge f(k/n)$

Comment: just make the sum of inequalities

Comment: look at the ajotatxe's answer... he have right?

Answer (score 0):

The sequence
$$I_n=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{1+\frac kn}$$
is strictly decreasing and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}I_n=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x}$$
Hence, the integral is lesser than the Riemann sums.

To show that the sequence is decreasing:
$$I_{n+1}-I_n=\frac1{2n+2}+\frac1{2n+1}-\frac1n<\frac1{2n}+\frac1{2n}-\frac1n=0$$